# How to use Browser.msgBox responses in google spreadsheet app?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying get the response of the user to do another action.

```
Browser.msgBox('Greetings', 'hello world', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
if (response == Browser.Buttons.YES) {
Logger.log('The user clicked "Yes."');
} else {
Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');
}
```

but this does not work. "response is not defined" error shows up. How do I get the response?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a closer look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#msgboxtitle-prompt-buttons). It returns a String containing the "lower case text of the button that is clicked by the user (or 'cancel' for a dismissed dialog)".

You also need to save the return value in the `response` variable.

```
var response = Browser.msgBox('Greetings', 'hello world', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
if (response == "yes") {
  Logger.log('The user clicked "Yes."');
} else {
  Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how it works :

```
  var response = Browser.msgBox('Greetings', 'hello world', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
  Logger.log(response);
  if (response == "yes") {
    Logger.log('The user clicked "Yes."');
  } else {
    Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');
  }
```

Browser method that ask for a response option returns a string, you could have used the logger like in the code above to check it.
So we have to use a condition on that string to check the result.

Answer (score 0):

I like the UI method more, do not have to hardcode response:

```
 var response = ui.alert('Are you sure you want to continue?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
    Logger.log('The user clicked "Yes."');
  } else {
    Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');
  }
```

[Sourse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/button-set)